# Rating algorithm based on a review scorecard with multiple sections

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math

I have an evaluation scorecard that have two sections, each section has a weight, each section has a set of questions/criteria.

The scorecard works like this, I will explain with example :

- Scorecard Section $1$ has a weight of $74$
- Scorecard Section $2$ has a weight of $26$
- In each section, the total weight of questions are $100$.
- Section $2$ only becomes enabled if the overall score has exceeded or equal to specific score, in this example it is $64$.

The algorithm that I am trying to find/implement, is a one that can make section $2$ to be visible when section $1$ questions average result was $70/100$ but that won't convert to $64$ in our example, it is $70/100 \cdot 74 = 51.8$.

What algorithm I can use that can get me $70/100$ to be equal $64$ of total scorecard score, at the same time $100/100$ to be the $74$.

a detailed example :

scorecard $1$, wight $74$

- question $1$, weight $50$, rating $(1-10)$, if we assign $7$, then it is $35$
- question $2$, weight $50$, rating $(1-10)$, if we assign $7$, then it is $35$
- section total score is $70/100$ so the overall score is $51.8$
  scorecard $2$, weight $26$ so the score here is $0$
  total score is $51.8$

The result of the algo should make the $70/10$ to be equal $64$ of total score. so we can make section $2$ visible.

If the scorecard $1$ got full score, then it is $74$. so section $2$ will be visible.

Is there an an algo that can help with that ?

I welcome any recommendation to change how we assign weight and calculate the whole thing, the thing about this evaluation scorecard, that section $2$ is used for evaluating the 'creativity' of the submission, so we only show it when the section $1$ score matches the minimum score requirement to evaluate it as a creative submission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found your explanation very confusing, to be honest, but as far as I understand, you meant something like the following, where $s_1$ and $s_2$ denote the scores from sections 1 and 2, respectively.

1. If $s_1<70$, let the final score be $(64/70)s_1$, not evaluating section 2 at all.
2. If $s_1\ge 70$, you have $100-64=36$ more points to assign, 26 of which are based on section 2, and the remaining 10 on section 1. So, the final score in that case is $64+(10/30)(s_1-70)+(26/100)s_2$.

Comment: I just did some testing and these formula seem exactly what I am looking for. One question: what does (10/30) mean in the 2nd formula ?

Comment: The 10 comes from the max 10 points that can be received from section 1 above the 64, and $30=100-70$, that is, the maximum value minus the threshold value of $s_1$.

Comment: Thank you! exactly what I need.